# Trying to populate an array using a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-value

So, I'm trying to populate and print a small array using functions, however I've hit a bit of a roadblock. The code I have is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct planes
{
    string name;
    int seats;
    int range;
    int weight;
};

int populate (planes planesArray[5])
{
    string name;
    int seats, range, weight, i;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("plane_data.txt");
    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "File cannot be reached";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        infile >> name;
        infile >> seats;
        infile >> range;
        infile >> weight;

    }

    infile.close();

}



int main() {

    planes planesArray[5];
    populate(planes planesArray[5]);

};
```

I'm getting a multitude of errors in the different iterations of code I'm using. With this one pasted above I am getting:

```
line 44: error: expected primary expression before (planesArray)
```

I'm a bit lost to be honest. There are 5 pieces of data in the array, I just don't know how to get the data from the file into the array reliably using the functions I've created.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That line should just say `populate(planesArray);`. You aren't supposed to mention the type of a variable every time you use it.

Comment: @BrianBi Now that I've done that for the function header, it is saying I need , or ; before the { token.

Comment: In the function header, you do need the type. Think of it as the declaration of the function's parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main() {
  planes planesArray[5];
  populate( planesArray); // this is how to call your function
}
^^^
note:  ; disappeared
```

When you call a function given some parameter you do not mention type of this parameter.

Next, you will try to implement your function. At the moment it does nothing with array parameter, but we won't provide ready tuned-in solution but rather help when you meet some concrete problems.

Comment: It still won't populate the array, but for a different reason.

Comment: real problem, and for sure first OP wants to overcome is compilation

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are unfit for such a task in C++, especially if you are new to the language. Use `std::vector` - and rename "planes" to "plane", which makes more sense (your struct represents *one* plane, not many).

```
int populate (std::vector<plane> &plane_vector)
{
  // ...
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<plane> plane_vector;
  populate(plane_vector);
}
```

This should fix the most blatant errors.

Comment: `std::array` is also a good choice for a fixed number of objects. It's basically like a C-style array without the problems.