# Trying to print the contents of an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm using a function to populate an array from a text file. As far as I can tell, the array is populating fine, but when I come to print the array using cout I get a lot of errors which say that the data from the file could not be converted to different data types (if these errors are required, comment to let me know).

The code I have so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct plane //strcutre of plane data to use
{
string name;
string direction;
int id;
int coordX;
int coordY;
int height;
int speed;

};

int populate (plane planeArray[5])
{
string name, direction;
int id, coordX, coordY, height, speed, i;
ifstream infile;                              //declare input file stream
infile.open("plane_data.txt");                //opens file
if (!infile)
{
    cout << "File cannot be reached";         //checks for invalid file path
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    infile >> planeArray.name[i];
    infile >> planeArray.direction[i];
    infile >> planeArray.id[i];
    infile >> planeArray.coordX[i];
    infile >> planeArray.coordY[i];
    infile >> planeArray.height[i];
    infile >> planeArray.speed[i];

}

infile.close();

}

void text_display(plane planeArray[5])
{
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    cout << planeArray[i].name << endl;
    cout << planeArray[i].id << endl;
    cout << planeArray[i].coordX << endl;
    cout << planeArray[i].coordY << endl;
    cout << planeArray[i].height << endl;
    cout << planeArray[i].speed << endl;
}
}


int main() {

plane planeArray[5];
populate( planeArray);
//text_display( planesArray);

};
```

Any input is appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: You never populate the array with the data from your file, and you never implemented `operator<<` for `plane`. Basically your program does nothing.

Comment: How do you know the array is populating fine? Your code doesn't appear to be populating it. It's just overwriting local variables with values from the file.

Comment: you can't use the `<<` operator for a `struct plane` without defining it first. Do something like `cout << playArray[i].name` if you don't want to define the operator yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to populate an array using a function in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021745/trying-to-populate-an-array-using-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Okay, so I've added the .name etc after the couts and I am no longer getting errors but nothing is printing.

Comment: @Michael Delahorne See my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to print an object of class `plane`, right here: `cout << planeArray[i] << endl;`. The compiler is giving you errors, because it simply doesn't know how to do that. Depending on what you want to do, you could change the line to:

```
cout << &planeArray[i] << endl;
```

to print the address, or

```
cout << planeArray[i].name << endl;
cout << planeArray[i].direction << endl;
cout << planeArray[i].id << endl;
cout << planeArray[i].coordX << endl;
cout << planeArray[i].coordY << endl;
cout << planeArray[i].height << endl;
cout << planeArray[i].speed << endl;
```

if you need the data of a specific object.

Moreover, if you want to do it you way (which is certainly possible), you can tell the compiler how to do that. Simply define an overloaded `operator<<`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const plane& myObject){
    // here goes the code from above
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I've added the .name etc after the couts and I am no longer getting errors but nothing is printing

Comment: That's because you're not assigning data from the file to the propper variables. Instead of doing - for example - `infile >> name;`, do `infile >> planeArrat[i].name`.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have seen that one, sorry. I'm now getting errors that are saying 
error: request for member 'name' in 'planeArray', which is of pointer type 'plane*'

Comment: Sorry, for each cout in the for loop inside of the populate function, i'll update the code in my post now.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << planeArray[i] << endl;
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
            |
            -> of type 'struct plane'
```

As you haven't overload `<<` for `struct plane`, you cannot directly put it after `<<`.

You need to change it to

```
cout << planeArray[i].name << endl;
...
cout << planeArray[i].speed << endl;
```

---

And you have to save the data before you can later print them out.

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    infile >> name;    // you read the data, but then throw them away...
    ...
    infile >> speed;
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    infile >> planeArray[i].name;
    ...
    infile >> planeArray[i].speed;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I've added the .name etc after the couts and I am no longer getting errors but nothing is printing

Answer (score 0):

The program has several errors. Let start from the auxiliary functions.

```
int populate (plane planeArray[5])
{
    string name, direction;
    int id, coordX, coordY, height, speed, i;
    ifstream infile;                              //declare input file stream
    infile.open("plane_data.txt");                //opens file
    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "File cannot be reached";         //checks for invalid file path
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        infile >> name;
        infile >> direction;
        infile >> id;
        infile >> coordX;
        infile >> coordY;
        infile >> height;
        infile >> speed;
    }

    infile.close();
}
```

First of all this function need additional parameter that will report the number of elements in the array. The problem is that these function declarations are equivalent

```
int populate (plane planeArray[5]);
int populate (plane planeArray[10]);
int populate (plane planeArray[]);
int populate (plane *planeArray);
```

So it would be better to declare this function as

```
int populate (plane planeArray[, int n );
```

where n is the number of elements in the array.

Further you are trying to enter data even if the input file wan not open.

```
    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "File cannot be reached";         //checks for invalid file path
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        infile >> name;
        // other stuff
```

The function is declared as having return type `int` but it returns nothing. I would declare it as having return type either  `void` or `bool`

```
bool populate (plane planeArray[], int n );
```

In the loop you are entering data in local variables. The array itself is not being changed.

Taking into account all that has been said the function could look the following way

```
bool populate (plane planeArray[], int n );
{
    ifstream infile( "plane_data.txt" );

    if ( !infile )
    {
        cout << "File cannot be reached";         //checks for invalid file path
        return false;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; infile && i < n; i++ )
    {
        infile >> planeArray[i].name;
        infile >> planeArray[i].direction;
        infile >> planeArray[i].id;
        infile >> planeArray[i].coordX;
        infile >> planeArray[i].coordY;
        infile >> planeArray[i].height;
        infile >> planeArray[i].speed;
    }

    return ( true );
}
```

Function text_display also is in valid

```
void text_display(plane planeArray[5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << planeArray[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Structure plane has no overloaded operator << so this statement

```
        cout << planeArray[i] << endl;
```

is invalid. The compiler will issue an error when it will parse this statement.

Should be

```
void text_display( plane planeArray[], int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        cout << planeArray[i].name << endl;
        cout << planeArray[i].direction << endl;;
        cout << planeArray[i].id << endl;;
        cout << planeArray[i].coordX << endl;;
        cout << planeArray[i].coordY << endl;;
        cout << planeArray[i].height << endl;;
        cout << planeArray[i].speed << endl;;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

And at last main will look as

```
int main() 
{
    const int N = 5;
    plane planeArray[N] = {};

    populate( planeArray, N );
    text_display( planesArray, N );
}
```

There is no need to place a semicolon after the closing brace. Otherwise it is an empty bstatement outside any function.